# PHP Header Redirect to 1 joomla site and retain domain in url without negatively affecting page ranking

Tags: php, joomla

I have 2 domains that need to go to specific parts of 1 joomla site.
I want the url to display per the one the user came to the site by.
Example:

1. domain-A.com is main site.  It will have links to domain-B.com
2. domain-B.com needs to be directed to a joomla menu item but be displayed as domain-B.com/...
   Meaning, if the user comes to the joomla site through domain-B.com the url should not be domain-A.com

I believe this is the way I should do it:
http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation

Code example:

```
`<?php
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$requri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (($domain == "www.example.de" && $requri == "/" || 
   $domain == "example.de"))  { 
   header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: http://www.example.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6"); 
}
?>`
```

**QUESTION:
Will this code negatively affect the search ranking for domain-B.com ?**

Answer (score 0):

You want domaina.com/article1 and domainb.com/article1 to display the same content (from the same Joomla install)?

If yes, then search ranking for domainb must be negatively affected since search engines will mark it's pages as duplicate content - one of Google's big no-no's.